# In SBT, Is it possible to add IntegrationTest config to a project using an AutoPlugin?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I'm developing an AutoPlugin and I want it to add the `IntegrationTest` config to projects that enable the plugin. Is this possible?

My first thought was this could be possible in the `buildSettings`, however examples I've seen for adding `IntegrationTest` config show achieved via a method call on a `Project` instance... i.e. ([from the SBT docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html#integration-tests)):

```
lazy val root =
  Project("root", file("."))
    .configs( IntegrationTest )
    .settings( Defaults.itSettings : _*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, just found this out myself:
Just like you can add settings by overriding `projectSettings`, you can add configs by overriding `projectConfigurations`.

Add something like this to your autoplugin:

`override val projectConfigurations = Seq(IntegrationTest)`